# Good geotagger / gps module for Nikon D750?

Tags: geotagging, gps, nikon-d750

I am looking for Geotagging addons for Nikon D750. What are the choices apart from the official one from Nikon - which is quite bulky and takes up the hotshoe.

Are there any bluetooth models in the market? Most of the bluetooth models I found via Google seem to have gone out of business.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you consider to use external GPS logger or mobile phone with such software?

Comment: `Most of the bluetooth models I found via Google seem to have gone out of business.` An excellent example of why asking for specific product recommendations is deemed not very useful on Photo.SE: after a while the answers are outdated and not useful. Voted to close. Perhaps [previous questions on geotagging](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geotagging) have more general solutions for your problem?

Comment: I don't think the D750 even supports Bluetooth.  The [D750 Product specs](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/dslr-cameras/d750.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs) only mention WiFi.  In comparison the [D7500 product specs](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/dslr-cameras/d7500.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs) explicitly mention Bluetooth.

Comment: Hi @PeterM - D750 doesn't need to support Bluetooth. The items I had found on Google consist of a GPS receiver that you carry on person, connected via bluetooth to this dongle that's plugged into the camera. The receiver passes on the co-ords to the dongle, which then conveys the information to the camera for tagging the photos.

Comment: @miCRoSCoPiC_eaRthLinG IMHO you should edit your question to show that, because as written, to me, it implies that you expect a bluetooth connection to the camera itself

Answer (score 2):

If you use Lightroom like I do, all you need to do is snap a photo with your cell phone to record the GPS, then at home in LR, import all your photos including the cell phone photos and sort them by time taken. Then, select the cell phone photo click the map module and it will show the location. Then just drag any other images taken around that time from your filmstrip to that location and they are all geo tagged. I tried an accessory GPS unit and it broke the first time out. This is much simpler. The file structure I use (which Lightroom follows on import, is:
Year, YearMo, YearMoDay ...like this.
2021
202101
20210101 (with all the images, sorted by date taken)

I'm usually the only one using the camera so my wife always takes a phone shot, doesn't matter of what ...even a pile of sand, since all we 'need' from that one is the time taken and the GPS coordinate.
We've travelled all over and using the Map module is great because you can also get information about the area, like landmarks etc. and add that to your keywording.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with GPS logging from external device I can offer to use [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.basicairdata.graziano.gpslogger) or [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mendhak.gpslogger) for Android. Both work well for me. Also you can use GPS navigation software as GPS logger (I know iGO can do this).

If you are fine with external device something like [this](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00EYC5GIQ) can help you.

After this you can use [Geotag software](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geotag/files/geotag) to load the GPS logs, resolve the place, city and tag your photo.

N.B. No affiliation with any of the manufacturers or sellers.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know of Bluetooth gps, but here is a hotshot option For a D750. I have a Nikon Z 6, and the Solmeta unit is small and unobtrusive. Good luck exploring options.